# transforming custom timestamp into different format

Tags: ksh

I have a time stamp that doesn't adhere with the standard unix timestamp format:

```
*** October 31, 2015 9:22:30 PM IST ***
```

I need to convert that into the following format:

```
YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS
```

Thing is, I know I can do the following:

1) write something that translates months into numbers.

2) extract the rest of the data through regular expression

3) convert 9pm to 21...

The question is: is there an easier way to do this? what would be the most optimal way to do this conversion?

I tried `date +Y%M%D_H%M%S` but the format is not the same, it doesn't match the `date` format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GNU date

date -d 'October 31, 2015 9:22:30 PM IST' +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"

In general, if the input date is in a shell variable, say d1,

date -d "$d1" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"